# iOS Development against custom backend

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, vagrant

I'm working on an iOS app with a small team of developers.  The app has a fairly extensive custom API on the backend on which the app is reliant.

My question is:

On larger teams developing iOS apps with custom backends (Rails, Node, etc), what is the general process for iOS developers to do their dev work against the backend?

1) We have Vagrant box for the API developers.  Should iOS do a localhost build against that?

- This seems problematic to me because the developer needs their Vagrant box setup to get any iOS work done.  So if they were work remotely on a different machine one day, they have to setup the Vagrant box to develop (maybe not a huge issue)

2) Just rely on a singular remote Staging server?

- This is an issue because as the team grows, everyone will be working on features that they want to test.  Furthermore, its a bit of a pain to have to do the whole Staging CI pipeline, every time you want to try out a change.

3) Have individual, remote Dev boxes for each developer

- This seems interesting.  Essentially, making scaled down versions of the app on a single box, and each dev gets a remote box (on AWS).  May nearly fall into free / very cheap tiers of AWS.  However, this would require a fair bit of work to setup, and to keep this ever-growing batch of Dev boxes in sync with Staging / Production may be painful

How is this generally approached?